# how to detect main function pefile python?

Tags: python

I am trying to detect the `main` function of a program using python pefile.

So far, I've been able to obtain the `.text` segment and disassemble it just fine as below:

```
pe = pefile.PE(filename, fast_load=True)

for sec in pe.sections():
    if sec.contains_rva(pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint):
        textSegment(pe.get_memory_mapped_image()[sec.PointerToRawData:sec.PointerToRawData + sec.SizeOfRawData], sec.SizeOfRawData)


def textSegment(data, dataLength):
    md = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64)
    md.detail = True
    for i in md.disasm(data, dataLength):
        print(i)
```

This disassembles the complete text segment of the binary including the main function. But I am looking to detect the start of the main function.

Can anyone tell me how do I find the main function here?

Answer (score 0):

And this is why you should never over work your brain, the answer is latterly in-front of you and you wouldn't notice it.

`pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint`
points to the entry point/main function of the program.

Comment: great you solved it, if this answers your question, please accept (click green check mark) to close this question from the open questions queue thanks! :)